# I would like to apply an emission shader to specific parts of a texture

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

[image: Genji]

I would like to add the emission shader to the green parts of this texture. How would I do that?
Edit: How do I make a mask from this texture

Comment: You should create a mask texture that is all black except for the emitting parts which should be white

Comment: Your going to want something lie this: http://imgur.com/a/8fcEJ I did this in photoshop, just select the colour range of green and then converted all of the green parts to white and put it over a black background.

Comment: May the dragon consume you! ;) Any reason the green areas do not have their own material? My first guess is that you have a geometry limit.

Answer (score 9):

First of all you'll need a map that will define the areas where light is being emitted from, like this: [image: Emission Map]
Then to mask it over the diffuse map you'll need to create a simple node setup where you use the new texture to control the way two shaders mix, the white areas will use one shader, the dark ones the other one:

[image: Node Setup]

(You don't have to use a diffuse node, I just used it for the example) Your final result should be something like this: [image: Final Result] 
Obviously yours will be on the actual model. Hope this helps.